# Drop rows based on condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11
```

What I need to do is to sum the C and D and if the sum is higher than 10 remove the entire row. Howerver I can't acess the columns by their names, I need to do it by their position.

How can I do it in pandas?

EDIT:
Another problem.

```
   A  B   C   D
0  0  NaN   2   3
1  4  5   NaN   NaN
2  8  9  10  11
```

How can I keep the rows that have at least two values in the columns B, C and D?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select rows from a DataFrame based on column values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/how-to-select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-column-values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep  the rows that have at least two values in the columns B, C and D.
You can use this.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0,4,8], 'B':[1, np.nan, 9], 'C':[2,np.nan, np.nan], 'D':[3, 7, 11]})
mask = df.iloc[:,1:].isnull().sum(axis=1) < 2
print(df[mask])
```

**output**

```py
    A   B   C   D
0   0   1.0 2.0 3
2   8   9.0 NaN 11
```

For your first question you should fill remaining `nan` values using `df.fillna()`,
[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) before moving with solution provided in earlier answers

```py
df = new_df.fillna(0)
print(df)
```

**Output**

```py
   A    B    C   D
0  0  1.0  2.0   3
2  8  9.0  0.0  11
```

Now you can use `df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1) <= 10]` to drop the rows where the sum of `C` and  `D` is more than 10.

Finally I recommend you to keep 1 post per question, this helps other people to search for it.

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you access the columns by names?  If you really can't, you can do this:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 4, 8], 'B': [1, 5, 9], 'C': [2, 6, 10], 'D': [3, 7, 11]})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
   A  B   C   D
0  0  1   2   3
1  4  5   6   7
2  8  9  10  11

In [4]: df.loc[df.iloc[:, 2:].sum(axis=1) <= 10]
Out[4]:
   A  B  C  D
0  0  1  2  3
```

Comment: The column names are very complex and full of blankspaces, I'm having a hard time to fix it

Answer (score 0):

This is:

```
df[(df['C']+df['D']) <= 10]
```